# equicontinuity of continuous functions defined on [a,b] which are α-Holder

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-continuity

I saw this problem in Charles Chapman Pugh's Mathematical Analysis :

> Consider a modulus of continuity $\mu (s) = H^\alpha$ where $0 <
> \alpha\leq1$ and $0 < H < \infty$. A function with this modulus of
>   continuity is said to be $\alpha$-Holder, with $\alpha$-Holder
>   constant $H$ .
>
> $(a)$ Prove that the set $C^\alpha(H)$ of all continuous functions
>   defined on $[a , b]$ which are $\alpha$-Holder and have
>   $\alpha$-Holder constant $\leq$ H is equicontinuous .
>
> $(b)$ Replace $[a , b]$ with $(a , b)$ . Is the same thing true?
>
> $(c)$ Replace $[a , b]$ with $\mathbb{R}$ Is it true?
>
> $(d)$ What about $\mathbb{Q}$?
>
> $(e)$ What about $\mathbb{N}$ ?

But basically here's my problem :

Part $(a)$ is easy as you can control $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq H|x-y|^\alpha$ everywhere by controlling $|x-y|$.
But I don't know the story will be different for next parts or not ?!
Did we really used any feature of closed interval $[a,b]$ in part $(a)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did we really used any feature of closed interval $[a,b]$ in part (a) ?

No, you did not.

> the story will be different for next parts or not ?!

It will not be any different. The same reasoning you applied for $[a,b]$ works for every metric space.